# How to use React Native ART library ARC method to draw an pie

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

why the arc method of React native ART lib is so confusing and drawing an arc is so complicated.

here is the doc of the arc but not a single line to understand about parameters passed. 
https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md

can you please help me understanding this arc method and how it works. I need to draw an arc between angle 0 to 270 degree based on a value calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [rn-art-d3-examples](https://github.com/gazdagergo/rn-art-d3-examples/blob/master/src/pie/PieChartBasic.js) the react component for Arc generation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ART } from 'react-native';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';

const d3 = {
  shape
};

const { Surface, Group, Shape } = ART;

const Arc = ({ size = 100, outerRadius = 40, innerRadius = 30, startAngleRad = 0, endAngleRad = 4 }) => {

  const width = size;
  const height = size;

  const arcGenerator =
    d3.shape
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .startAngle(startAngleRad)
      .endAngle(endAngleRad);

  const x = width / 2;
  const y = height / 2;

  return (
    <View>
      <Surface width={width} height={height}>
        <Group x={x} y={y}>
          <Shape
            key="arc"
            d={arcGenerator()}
            fill="#FFF"
          />
        </Group>
      </Surface>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Arc;
```

Comment: as a side-note you have to install d3-shape library too https://github.com/d3/d3-shape

Comment: @gazdagergo can you help me draw shape like this.. https://github.com/doc-ai/react-native-arc-progress..

Comment: I suggest to draw two shapes on top of each other. To top one sholud have different end angle. Plus set a dark blue stroke to both shapes while the top one's fill is ligth blue and the bottom one is dark blue.

Comment: ART is no longer part of react-native.  It got extracted out in order to reduce react-native's footprint.  It now needs to be loaded separately, as explained here: https://github.com/react-native-community/art.  Even with that caveat, this is still a very useful answer.